# What is the meaning of the kli Yakar Bereshis 44:21

Tags: hebrew, translation, acharonim, vayigash

What is the meaning of this line in  (kli Yakar Bereshis 44:21)

כי הבחינה היינו דרישה וחקירה כקטן מסיח לפי תומו, ולא נתרצו האחים לזה, כי    אמרו פן ילמדוהו לדבר תועה ובחרו לישב במאסר

Comment: Could you please [edit] in what you understand and what, in particular, you don't?

Comment: Hello sy1 and welcome to mi.yodeya! As @IsaacMoses said, this question would be strengthened by giving some context for the comment. Is your question based on translation, questioning premises, utter confusion over the comparison made, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The stuff  quoted  in the question is not sufficient. To explain, we need an extended quote (see below):

> אלא לפי שיוסף אמר להם שעל ידי בנימין הוא רוצה לבחון דבריהם כמ"ש **בזאת תבחנו** וגו' (בראשית מ"ב, ט"ו), וא"כ היה רצונו לשום עיניו עליו ולראות על ידו אם דבריהם כנים או לא. והמפרשים אמרו שמתחלה נאמר שם ויבחנו דבריכם.ואחר שהיו במאסר אמר להם ויאמנו דבריכם, כי הבחינה היינו דרישה וחקירה כקטן מסיח לפי תומו, ולא נתרצו האחים לזה, כי אמרו פן ילמדוהו לדבר תועה ובחרו לישב במאסר, ואח"כ הוציאם מן המאסר ואמר להם ויאמנו דבריכם בלא דרישה וחקירה, ולזה נתרצו להביאו, וע"כ אמר לו כאן שאתה אמרת ואשימה עיני עליו כי בהבאתו לבד תראה שדברינו נאמנו מאוד, ואיך נהפכת עליו כרגע להתגולל ולהתנפל עלינו.‏

We will follow the argument of the Keli Yakar step by step.

The Keli Yakar is explaining a verse in the previous parasha (42, 15):

> בְּזֹ֖את **תִּבָּחֵ֑נוּ**  חֵ֤י פַרְעֹה֙ אִם-תֵּֽצְא֣וּ מִזֶּ֔ה כִּ֧י אִם-בְּב֛וֹא אֲחִיכֶ֥ם הַקָּטֹ֖ן הֵֽנָּה:‏
>
> Hereby you **shall be tested**; By the life of Pharaoh you shall not go from here, except if your youngest brother comes here.

The Keli Yakar explains the word "תבחנו" "shall be tested" in this verse. Yosef wanted to interview  the young brother, to verify they were telling the truth. Kli Yakar says that commentators are focusing on a change in the manner in which Yosef expresses the reason of his need to speak with the young brother. in verse 42, 16, he says:

> שִׁלְח֨וּ מִכֶּ֣ם אֶחָד֘ וְיִקַּ֣ח אֶת-אֲחִיכֶם֒ וְאַתֶּם֙ הֵאָ֣סְר֔וּ
>
> **וְיִֽבָּֽחֲנוּ֙ דִּבְרֵיכֶ֔ם** הַֽאֱמֶ֖ת אִתְּכֶ֑ם וְאִם-לֹ֕א
>
> חֵ֣י פַרְעֹ֔ה כִּ֥י מְרַגְּלִ֖ים אַתֶּֽם:‏
>
> Send one of you, and let him fetch your brother, and you shall be kept in prison, that **your words may be proved**, whether there is any truth in you; or else by the life of Pharaoh surely you are spies.

The commentators explained that "בחינה" (testing) refers to a detailed questioning about the facts {see Sanhedrin chapter 4}, there is an advantadge to interview a child, who responds spontaneously to questions. The brothers did not accept such an approach. **They were worried Binyamin get confused and say something against them because Yosef will causing him to confuse.** They chose therefore  to go to jail. Afterward, Yosef  released them from prison and change his way of talking, saying  "ויאמינו דבריכם" (your words will be taken seriously). Her ccorrected his  vocabulary  and said that he want not  to ask the young brother anything. Then, they agreed to bring him. According to this we understand the words of Yehuda "you said 'ואשימה עיני עליו'". The fact that he comes is a sufficient proof that we tell the truth. How have you changed your mind about him and you, against us.
I hope that this help a little bit.